# In vue after assigning variable it still points to old variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, reference

```
created(){
  this.approvalStepList = this.selectedVoucher.approvalStepList;  // not sorted

  this.approvalStepList
    .sort(function(a,b){
      if (new Date(a.createDate) < new Date(b.createDate)) return -1;
      if (new Date(a.createDate) > new Date(b.createDate)) return 1;
      return 0;
  });

  this.approvalStepList; // now sorted

  this.selectedVoucher.approvalStepList.sort(function(a,b){
    return  new Date(a.createDate) - new Date(b.createDate)
  })[0].step==2;

  this.approvalStepList  // now again not sorted anymore, although its not touched in the command before
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you're assigning at the beginning the pointer to the `this.selectedVoucher.approvalStepList` - in this line:

```
this.approvalStepList = this.selectedVoucher.approvalStepList;  // not sorted
```

Instead, you should try to assign a copy of that array, e.g. using spread operator:

```
this.approvalStepList = [...this.selectedVoucher.approvalStepList];
```

So what was happening there - because you were not doing a clone, but variable assignment, these two values were binded together as they were pointing to the same object in the memory - so anything you would one to each of them would affect both of them as well. When you perform a copy it should work, I can provide you a simple example:

[image: l]